# Allow Session ID to persist after release

Tags: refresh-token, session-id

we're using a Session ID (retrieved via the following command) to access a few of our Salesforce APIs from external sources.

> `curl https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token -d
>   "grant_type=password" -d "client_id=myclientid" -d
>   "client_secret=myclientsecret" 
>       -d "username=mylogin@salesforce.com" -d "password=mypassword123456"`

However, on every release, this is invalidated and it takes a lot of work to reset and update.  Is there a better/easier way to handle this?

Comment: What is the context? Are you attempting to establish a persistent connect from some external web server? Who does it authenticate as?

Comment: @DavidReed we have a job on an external web server that hits a Salesforce endpoint ~every 10 mins to pick up new records to process.  It's authenticating as a User created specifically for this task

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend using the JWT flow for this use case, not the username-password flow.

There is a nice [guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_auth.htm) to doing headless JWT authentication in the Salesforce DX Developer Guide. You don't have to use SFDX to do this; there are JWT libraries available for many languages.

The benefit of using JWT is that your application can always obtain a new token (and in fact, always must be prepared to do so, since you don't get a refresh token), and is always ready to do so in a headless fashion - no user intervention required past initial setup.

Since you can assign a Permission Set to your integration user and preauthorize that Permission Set on your Connected App, you can tightly scope the availability of this authorization pathway and make sure your org stays secure.